# Linear layout, doesnt appear as wanted

Tags: java, android-studio

So basically kinda new to android studio and I've gotten stuck at this problem which takes too much time..

As the title says and the image I'm providing - The outcome that I want doesnt match.. 
The "x" is supposed to be my personal info later on. I want the emulator to look like as the left picture.

Any help is appreciated.

***I got everything to work except the theme "DarkactionBar".***

[image]

Here's my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="71dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CvIntro"
        style="@style/Mitt_CV_STIL"
        android:layout_width="284dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/CvIntro" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="TillCV"
        android:text="@string/button1"


        />


</LinearLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: how are you defining the app theme? Care to show the manifest and the style file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have change your colors.xml under res/values folder. In colors.xml you need to change colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark, colorAccent etc as per your required colors.

where colorPrimary is the toolbar color, and color accent is view items color.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here

```
tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"
```

tools namespace is used only for design-time purpose, read here
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes

Comment: The image was pretty much only for an example, didnt wanna provide my own photo for the community to see. I did try with my own attached photo, still didnt work.

Comment: you have to use app namespace -> `app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_image"`
`

Comment: I did. Somehow I got the img and all to work but not the theme. Any tips?

Comment: click on the icon next to sdk version and select the your theme

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your xml layout from the code below.
Hope this will help

***I got everything to work except the theme "DarkactionBar".***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CvIntro"
        android:layout_width="284dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/CvIntro" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="TillCV"
        android:text="@string/button1"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```